# Extract X_train from .flow_from_directory

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0

I import my dataset like below:

```
path = './train'
img_gen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator()
train_set = img_gen.flow_from_directory(path,(224, 224),'rgb', batch_size=8)
```

I would like to write X_train and Y_train, with Y_train are the labels, for Y_train , I write this :

```
train_set.classes
```

How extract `X_train`  ???

Answer (score 0):

[flow_from_directory](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/image/#flowfromdirectory-method) returns and iterator, so you have to iterate over it to get a batch of (x,y) tuples. You can use:

```
for x, y in train_set:
   print (x, y)
```

Note that you will get a batch rather then a single sample per iteration.